# What is the maximum number of intersections of two sigmoid curves?

Tags: real-analysis, roots, curves

I have two specific sigmoid functions with domain in $[0,\infty)$ that depend on a common set of parameters. I was able to show that they have the same limit at infinity and that the dashed curve is above the back curve at $0$ (please see figure below). I now need to show that they do not intersect. I was wondering if there are any general results on the maximum number of intersections of two sigmoid curves? It seems to be $3$, but I haven't been able to obtain a proof for this. Such a result would definitely be a good start for me. Any suggestion is much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: @PeterForeman The functions are series of the form $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty c_k \frac{1}{(1+e^x)^k}$. Both functions have the same coefficient $c_0$, the other coefficients depend on a set of parameters and can be defined recursively (but a bit long to write down).

Comment: so you would like to know which is the number of intersections of the two functions $\sum_{k=1} c_k(1+e^x)^{-k}$ and $\sum_{k=1} b_k(1+e^x)^{-k}$, right? (we can kill the coefficients $c_0$ and $b_0$).

Comment: I'm more interested in knowing whether there are any general results on the maximum number of intersections of two sigmoid curves. This would help me attack my problem. Just to be clear, I'm not saying that I don't want help on my specific problem. I just wanted to make my question more general so it might be helpful to others as well.

Comment: I agree, it is an interesting question, but you should provide a precide definition of what you mean by "sigmoid ", as you see it is quite general term that may refer to different functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function . For example: if all the sigmoids have the same asymptote, then there should be some additional constraint on the coefficients of the series.